# how to stay on the same page when the confirm button of a sweet alert is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert

This is the sweet-alert I am using and I am changing the color of a button from red to green when it is clicked.but I don't want the page to reload when the confirm button is clicked.The issue is that the sweet alert is not closing when I click the confirm button.any help would be appreciated greatly

```
 function UpdateChildStatus(id,status)
         {
             $.ajax({
               method:'get',
               url:'updateChildrenStatus',
               data:{id:id,status:status},
               success:function(result){
                    if (status===1)
                    {
                        swal({
                            title: "Successfully Enabled!",
                            type: "success",
                            showCancelButton: false,
                            confirmButtonColor: "#2ECC71",
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                            closeOnConfirm: true },
                                function (confirm) {
                                    location.reload();
                                });
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        swal({
                            title: "Successfully Disabled!",
                            type: "warning",
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonColor: "#E74C3C",
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                            closeOnConfirm: true },
                                function (confirm) {
                                     $("#'id'").attr('class', 'btn btn-block btn-success');
                                     event.preventDefault();


                                });
                    }
             },

            error:function(x, y, thrownError){
                    console.log(thrownError);
            }
         });
     }
```

Comment: Is `$("#'id'")` really working? Also, you should really use `addClass()` instead of setting the class names through `attr()`

Comment: Try e.preventDefault() , because submit buttons natural behavior is to redirect.

Comment: e.preventDefault() is not working :/ and I cannot check whether $("#'id'") is working cuz when the page refreshes the color changes automatically because the value change in the db..I commented out that line to see whether it interferes with the execution but still the alert doesn't close

Answer (score 2):

if you are calling the function from your html like this:

```
<button onclick="someFunc()">,
```

You need to change that to

```
<button onclick="return someFunc()">
```

also, at the end of your function in javascript, add:

```
return false;
```

That should be enough to prevent the page from reloading on click. If you could provide your code a little bit in detail, I can modify it for you. :)

Comment: I included the full code of the js function above :) I am in a bit of a fix here and I would be much obliged if you can do that :)

Comment: @KashifRoshen One last thing, how are you calling your function? I mean you used "onclick" in your html or did you use jquery .click event?

Comment: I used onclick :) I did what I told above and it is working :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)